# AVFoundation crash in fetching averagePowerLevel from audio connection

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I have the following code to update power level meters from AVAudioConnection periodically.

```
  func updateMeters() {
    var channelCount = 0
    var decibels:[Float] = []
    
    let audioConnection = self.audioConnection
    
    if let audioConnection = audioConnection {
        
        for audioChannel in audioConnection.audioChannels {
            decibels.append(audioChannel.averagePowerLevel)
            channelCount = channelCount + 1
        }
    }
}
```

But some of my users are getting crashes in this code:

```
  Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
  *** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]

  Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
 0  CoreFoundation                 0x99288 __exceptionPreprocess
 1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x16744 objc_exception_throw
 2  CoreFoundation                 0x1a431c -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:].cold.1
 3  CoreFoundation                 0x4c96c CFDateFormatterCreateStringWithAbsoluteTime
 4  AVFCapture                     0x6cad4 -[AVCaptureConnection getAvgAudioLevelForChannel:]
 5  MyApp.                        0x65ce0 updateMeters + 4692 (CapturePipeline.swift:4692)
 6  MyApp                         0x6da64 <name omitted> + 980 (CapturePipeline.swift:980)
 7  MyApp                         0x49324 <name omitted> (<compiler-generated>)
 8  Foundation                     0x3310c __NSFireTimer
 9  CoreFoundation                 0xae678 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
 10 CoreFoundation                 0x32654 __CFRunLoopDoTimer
 11 CoreFoundation                 0x2ce00 __CFRunLoopDoTimers
 12 CoreFoundation                 0xb4b0 __CFRunLoopRun
 13 CoreFoundation                 0x1ebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
 14 GraphicsServices               0x1374 GSEventRunModal
 15 UIKitCore                      0x514648 -[UIApplication _run]
 16 UIKitCore                      0x295d90 UIApplicationMain
 17 libswiftUIKit.dylib            0x30ecc UIApplicationMain(_:_:_:_:)
 18 MyApp                          0xc358 main (WhiteBalanceUI.swift)
 19 ???                            0x105169ce4 (Missing)
```

Has anyone encountered this crash I wonder.

Comment: Did you ever get any further with this? I am seeing the same issue with the following for some but not all audio devices:    
`let channels = connection.audioChannels.map ({ AudioPreview.Channel(level: $0.averagePowerLevel, volume: $0.volume, enabled: $0.isEnabled) })`    
Changing to a for in loop has the same effect.

Comment: @DanM No, I could not!

Comment: Thanks unfortunate. It seems to happen particularly with devices with lots of channels, but not all of them. If I have any insight I will report back.